# scrapy xpath : choose the ancestor node

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have a question about xpath

```
    <div id="A" >
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="area">
                    <div class="sec">USA</div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="">D1</a></td>
                                <td>D2</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td><a href="">E1</a></td>
                                <td>E2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="area">
                    <div class="sec">UK</div>
                    <table>
                        <tbody> 
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="">F1</a></td>
                                <td>F2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My code is:

```
sel = Selector(response)
group = sel.xpath("//div[@id='A']/div[@class='B']/div[@class='C']/div[@class='item']/div[@class='area']/table/tbody/tr")
for g in group:
    # section = g.xpath("").extract()  #ancestor???
    context = g.xpath("./td[1]/a/text()").extract()
    brief = g.xpath("./td[2]/text()").extract()
    # print section[0]
    print context[0]
    print brief[0]
```

it will print:

```
D1
D2
E1
E2
F1
F2
```

But I want to print :

```
USA
D1
D2
USA
E1
E2
UK
F1
F2
```

So I need to choose the value of the parent node so I can get `USA` and `UK`
I can't figure it out for a while.
Please teach me thank you!

Answer (score 12):

In *XPath*, you can traverse backwards a tree with `..` , so a selector like this could work for you:

```
section = g.xpath('../../../div[@class="sec"]/text()').extract()
```

Although this would work, it heavily depends on the exact document structure you have. If you need a bit more flexibility, to say allow minor structural changes to the document, you could search backwards for an ancestor like this:

```
section = g.xpath('ancestor::div[@class="area"]/div[@class="sec"]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 5):

http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathparent.php nice link.

Getting parent element can be done by `xpathchild/..`

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree, html
import urllib2

a='<div id="A" ><div class="B"><div class="C"><div class="item"><div class="area"><div class="sec">USA</div> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td><a href="">D1</a></td> <td>D2</td> </tr> <tr class="even"> <td><a href="">E1</a></td> <td>E2</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div> <div class="area"> <div class="sec">UK</div> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td><a href="">F1</a></td> <td>F2</td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div>'

tree = etree.fromstring(a)
print filter(lambda x:x.strip(),tree.xpath('//div[@class="area"]//text()'))
```

Output: ['USA', 'D1', 'D2', 'E1', 'E2', 'UK', 'F1', 'F2']

// - extract all descendants
/ - extracts only the direct child elements